# Spots on underside/interior of old wood shingles?

Tags: roof, roofing, shingles, asphalt

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJyIY.jpg

Garage has an uncovered interior ceiling which is just old cedar shakes ( there is asphalt shingles over it - about 15 years old). I’ve been noticing a heavy tar/asphalt smell as the weather is warming up while inside the garage. While looking for answers I noticed the “ceiling” has spots like this black one randomly throughout. I only moved in to this spot in April but I don’t recall any leaks while it rained earlier in the year. Any idea what a spot like this could be? Could this be some indicator of the tar smell?

Comment: Wow asphalt over cedar? We always stripped the shingles and decked the roof I have not seen asphalt or 3 tab over shingles but if it is up there it would be common to emit a tar smell on a hot day.

Comment: Would it still be possible to be emitting the tar odor even years later? And if so, would covering the old shingles with some drywall (or comparable) type ceiling help seal the odor you think?

Comment: On hot days the tar will smell like warm tar. You don’t smell shingles in a house that has decking and Sheetrock so it will probably seal the smell on the other side of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Might be seeping out of the shingles above, might be someone used a liquid asphalt patch product on some holes in the shingles above.

Comment: I’ll take a look and see in the morning if there’s any obvious signs of it on top!